# when I am creating static resource then I get error- "Expected metadata file with '-meta.xml' extension at path"

Tags: salesforcedx

can any one help for it-

> Missing Metadata File: Expected metadata file with '-meta.xml' extension at path: /Users/edcast/Desktop/trailblazer/helloworldlwc/force-app/main/default/staticresources/myguidescript.resource-meta.xml